# NSUnknownKeyException of UItextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

my code:

```
@interface UITextView ()
- (id)styleString; // make compiler happy
@end

@interface MBTextView : UITextView

@end


#import "MBTextView.h"

@implementation MBTextView
- (id)styleString {
    return [[super styleString] stringByAppendingString:@"; line-height: 1.2em"];
}
@end
```

and  i call:

```
[MBTextView setValue:@"<b>big</b><br>blah blah" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```

it give me NSUnknownKeyException.  but if i only used :

```
[UItextView setValue:@"<b>big</b><br>blah blah" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"]; all is ok.what wrong with my code?
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

sorry,it's my mistake:

```
[UItextView.text setValue:@"<b>big</b><br>blah blah" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```

i can't use text,sorry